# Как собрать проект PyQt в один исполняемый файл.exe?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, pyinstaller

В моей структуре проекта два файла, один из них **.py** второй **.ui** 
Пытаюсь сделать сборку через **`pyinstaller`**, 
но при создании сборки с флагом `-onefile` никак не подтягивается файл с расширением **.ui** и в итоге exe не запускается, если лежит не в одной директории с файлом **.ui**. 
А я хочу получить именно независимый **.exe**, чтобы он запускался из любого места на ПК.

Подскажите как сделать?

Comment: так сделайте из ui py файл

Comment: Через pyside6 сделал, а он все равно в сборку не добавляется. Вот и вопрос что не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть у вас есть два модуля:
**q1539328_main.py** и **q1539328.ui**

Пусть базовый класс вашего главного окна и вашей формы **`QMainWindow`**

---

Вам надо сделать:

1. `pyuic5 q1539328.ui -o q1539328_ui.py`
2. В модуле **q1539328_main.py**:

`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *                                      # ваши импорты

from q1539328_ui import Ui_MainWindow                       # !!! +++ Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):               # !!! +++ Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        
        self.setupUi(self)                                  # !!! +++ 
        
        ...
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ц = MainWindow()
    ц.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

`

3. `pyinstaller -F -w q1539328_main.py`
4. **q1539328_main.exe**

---

---

**Update**:

Пусть у вас есть два модуля:
**q1539328_main.py** и **language_form.ui**

Пусть базовый класс вашего главного окна и вашей формы **`QWidget`**

Вам надо сделать:

1. `pyuic5 language_form.ui -o language_form.py`

**language_form.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(603, 488)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 150, 131, 51))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.rus_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.rus_button.setObjectName("rus_button")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.rus_button)
        self.eng_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.eng_button.setObjectName("eng_button")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.eng_button)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 109, 281, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 220, 101, 21))
        self.label_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 210, 281, 111))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.line.setFrame(True)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.line)
        self.get_result = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.get_result.setObjectName("get_result")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.get_result)
        self.output_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.output_line.setReadOnly(True)
        self.output_line.setObjectName("output_line")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.output_line)
        self.result_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.result_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 290, 101, 21))
        self.result_label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.result_label.setObjectName("result_label")
        self.dots_num_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.dots_num_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 220, 161, 21))
        self.dots_num_label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.dots_num_label.setObjectName("dots_num_label")
        self.k_dots = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(Form)
        self.k_dots.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 250, 161, 31))
        self.k_dots.setMaximum(30)
        self.k_dots.setProperty("value", 10)
        self.k_dots.setObjectName("k_dots")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 150, 131, 54))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_3.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_3")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.esp_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.esp_button.setObjectName("esp_button")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.esp_button)
        self.chinese_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget_3)
        self.chinese_button.setObjectName("chinese_button")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.chinese_button)
        self.degree_box = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(Form)
        self.degree_box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 150, 161, 31))
        self.degree_box.setMinimum(2)
        self.degree_box.setMaximum(30)
        self.degree_box.setProperty("value", 2)
        self.degree_box.setObjectName("degree_box")
        self.choose_degree_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.choose_degree_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 110, 151, 31))
        self.choose_degree_label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.choose_degree_label.setObjectName("choose_degree_label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.rus_button.setText(_translate("Form", "Русский"))
        self.eng_button.setText(_translate("Form", "English"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Выберите язык:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Введите число"))
        self.get_result.setText(_translate("Form", "Вычислить"))
        self.result_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Результат:"))
        self.dots_num_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Цифр после запятой:"))
        self.esp_button.setText(_translate("Form", "Español"))
        self.chinese_button.setText(_translate("Form", "中国人"))
        self.choose_degree_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Выберите степень:"))
```

---

2. В модуле **q1539328_main.py**:

---

```
import sys
from math import sqrt
#from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel

from language_form import Ui_Form                             # - Ui_MainWindow
# ----------------------> ^^^^^^^ <--------------------------------------------


class LangForm(QWidget, Ui_Form):                             # - Ui_MainWindow
# --------------------> ^^^^^^^ <----------------------------------------------
    MISTAKE = ["ОШИБКА", 'ERROR', 'ERROR', '错误']
    LANG_NUM = 1
    ERROR_STATUS = False
    DEGREE = 2
# ???    mistake_text = ''
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(LangForm, self).__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
#        uic.loadUi('language_form.ui', self)

        self.label_2.setText('Введите число:')
        self.rus_button.clicked.connect(self.rus_form)
        self.eng_button.clicked.connect(self.eng_form)
        self.esp_button.clicked.connect(self.esp_form)
        self.chinese_button.clicked.connect(self.chinese_form)
        self.get_result.clicked.connect(self.print_result)

    def rus_form(self):
        self.label.setText('Выберите язык:')
        self.label_2.setText('Введите число:')
        self.get_result.setText('Вычислить')
        self.dots_num_label.setText('Цифр после запятой:')
        self.result_label.setText('Результат:')
        self.LANG_NUM = 1
        
    def eng_form(self):
        self.label.setText('Choose your language:')
        self.label_2.setText('Enter the number:')
        self.get_result.setText('Calculate')
        self.dots_num_label.setText('Numbers after dot:')
        self.result_label.setText('Result:')
        self.LANG_NUM = 2
        
    def esp_form(self):
        self.label.setText('Elige tu idioma:')
        self.label_2.setText('Introduce el número:')
        self.get_result.setText('Calcular')
        self.dots_num_label.setText('Números después del punto:')
        self.result_label.setText('Resultado:')
        self.LANG_NUM = 3
        
    def chinese_form(self):
        self.label.setText('选择你的语言:')
        self.label_2.setText('输入号码:')
        self.get_result.setText('计算')
        self.dots_num_label.setText('小数点后的数字:')
        self.result_label.setText('结果:')
        self.LANG_NUM = 4
        
    def print_result(self):
        self.DEGREE = self.degree_box.value()
        try:
            if float(self.line.text()) > 0:
                if self.k_dots.value() == int(self.k_dots.value()):
                    output = str(round(
                        float(self.line.text()) ** (1 / self.DEGREE), 
                        self.k_dots.value())
                    )
            else:
                output = float(self.line.text()) ** (1 / DEGREE)
            self.output_line.setText(str(output))
            self.ERROR_STATUS = False
        except Exception:
            self.output_line.setText('ОШИБКА / ERROR / 错误')
            self.ERROR_STATUS = True
            
            
# ???class SecondForm(QWidget):
# ???    def __init__(self):
# ???        super(LangForm, self).__init__()
# ???        uic.loadUi('calculation_form.ui', self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = LangForm()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

3. **pyinstaller -F -w q1539328_main.py**
4. **q1539328_main.exe**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можете пояснить что тут происходит в пункте 2?

Comment: @Tewqfry да, можно пояснить, но вы не сказали что именно вам не понятно. Я рекомендую вам опубликовать ваши модули и попытку того как вы попробовали реализовать выше описаннон.

Comment: вот я пытаюсь сделать импорт, а он красным подсвечен

Comment: from language_form.ui import Ui_MainWindow 
пишу в файле .py

Comment: https://www.online-python.com/DRZfde1so9 - вот мой код (эта песочница с pyqt вроде как не работает, просто для примера сюда закинул)
Почему продолжает подсвечиваться красным импорт??

Comment: @Tewqfry я обновил свой ответ, проверьте.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный и как полезный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: спасибо, это решило мою проблему